# How to interpret "jmp dword ptr [rel $00005e52]"?

Tags: assembly

I am trying to trace an assembly code in Win64 platform:

When instruction execute to:

```
0000000000402590 FF25525E0000     jmp dword ptr [rel $00005e52]
```

After the jump, it will go to address:

```
00000000006B3F90 56               push rsi
```

How the jmp instruction retrieve the address to jump to?  What is the meaning of [rel $00005e52] ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This particular jmp (listed as "FF /4 jmp r/m64" in the documentation) uses the so-called RIP-relative addressing (ModR/M byte = 0x25: mod=00b, reg/opcode=100b, r/m=101b; this means disp32 in 32-bit mode but RIP+disp32 in 64-bit mode).

It reads the jump address (64-bit) from 0x402590+6 (address of the instruction following this jmp) + 0x5E52, that is, from 0x4083E8. Memory at 0x4083E8 (8 bytes) should be equal to 0x6B3F90.